# not able to start nginx

Tags: nginx, rtmp, live-streaming, systemctl

i installed `nginx` in my machine and it installed correctly but not able to start `nginx` in my machine and whenever i try to start the `nginx` it shows error below i mentioned.
whenever i run the command `systemctl restart nginx && systemctl status nginx` 
i got the error message :

```
`Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with 
   error code.See "systemctl  status nginx.service" and "journalctl  - 
  xe" for details.`
```

after excuting the command : `systemctl  status nginx.service`

following output is produces:

```
  `nginx.service - The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor 
   preset: e Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-09-10 
  14:57:14 IST;32s ago Process: 6321 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t 
  (code=exited ,status=203/EXEC)`

`Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting The NGINX HTT
Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control
Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start The NG
Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit en
Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed`
```

after excuting the command :
`journalctl  -xe` ,the output genreated is:

```
 `-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
   Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC 
   systemd[6321]:nginx.service: Fail
   -- Subject: Process /usr/sbin/nginx could not be executed
   -- Defined-By: systemd
   -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
   -- 
   -- The process /usr/sbin/nginx could not be executed and failed.
   -- 
   -- The error number returned by this process is 2.
   Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: 
   nginx.service: 
   Control
   Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Failed to 
   start The NG
   -- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
   -- Defined-By: systemd
   -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
   -- 
   -- Unit nginx.service has failed.
   -- 
   -- The result is failed.
   Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit en
   Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]:nginx.service: Failed 
   Sep 10 14:57:14 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC polkitd(authority=local) [751]: Unr
   Sep 10 14:57:46 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1] Configuration file /li
   Sep 10 14:57:46 hk-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]:Configuration file /li`
```

search for the solution for this but didn't found any..Any help will be appreciated.

error log:
        `2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/10 15:50:47 [emerg] 7972#7972: still could not bind()`

Comment: Is there an `nginx` error log?

Comment: posted the error lo above.

Answer (score 1):

Like the last error says you are using the port 80, check if you have apache on port 80

userful command:

> netstat -tlpn

Comment: yes port is in used. now i killed the process at port:80 and excute the command `systemctl restart nginx && systemctl status nginx` and it shows :       
         `nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
          Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-09-10 16:03:16 IST; 16ms ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 8903 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code
  Process: 8902 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process 
.....`

Comment: thanks! it worked. i was stuck at this and couldn't think of that.